# AWS SQS Exception “Error code:413 Request Entity Too Large”

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying get messages from Amazon SQS, but I am getting the 413 error.

```
com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: null (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 413; Error Code: 413 Request Entity Too Large; Request ID: null; Proxy: null)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1819)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1403)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1372)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2283)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2250)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2239)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeReceiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1665)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1633)
```

Here is the code snippet.

```
ReceiveMessageRequest rmr = new ReceiveMessageRequest(getQueueURL(queueName));
                    rmr.setMaxNumberOfMessages(itemsToFetch);
                    rmr.setWaitTimeSeconds(1);
                    rmr.setAttributeNames("All");
                    ReceiveMessageResult receiveMessage = amazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(rmr);
                    messages = receiveMessage.getMessages();
```

But when I checked the SQS on Amazon none of the messages are more than 180 bytes, Even I tried to fetch only message when I see this error. But no luck.

1. If the message is not more than 180 Bytes, Why it is giving error?
2. How should we handle this error, if I want to ignore and continue?

Comment: Please Edit your message to show your code, and the contents of the request being sent so that we can try to reproduce your situation.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Added code snippet.

Comment: can you share your sample SQS message ?

Comment: Is it the `receiveMessage()` that is causing the error? I wonder if the request is being sent to the correct destination. Are other AWS API calls working in that program? I'm just wondering if the Region is set incorrectly so it isn't getting to the SQS Endpoint?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am receiving messages till I get this error. Yes, I am receiving error when I try to call receive message.  Does fetching All attributes considered as size of the message?

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting thought! Do you have any particularly large Attributes? If you don't need to retrieve all of the attributes, you can try reducing or removing this.

Comment: I did the changes, we will monitor it for few days and update the results here. Thanks for your time @JohnRotenstein